# spring org.springframework.asm and org.springframework.context.support compatible with spring 4.3.7

Tags: java, spring

Im new to the spring framework and i got stuck at this point.. What version of org.springframework.asm and org.springframework.context.support is compatible with spring 4.3.7?

Comment: asm is part of spring-core, and context is one of the modules of spring-framework, and the compatible version thus has the same version number ( 4.3.7-RELEASE) as the other modules of the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer at spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/overview-summary.html and as JB mentioned n comment ASM is part of spring core and the spring-core and spring context version was different in my case and  same version of both jars solved the problem.